# Using 'LIKE' against column names in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I started to take a look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616458/sql-query-like-clarification

Unfortunately it appeared that the original question was somewhat unclear however I decided to interpret this as him trying to only run his query when certain columns in the schema matched his like condition. It's very possible that this wasn't what was being asked however I wanted to challenge myself to do this (posted as a new question since the original was unclear and likely to be deleted and very possible nothing related to this).

What I got to was the following:

```
select 
       [OrderID]
      ,[ProductID]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[Discount]
from [Northwind].[dbo].[Order Details]
where
    (
        select top 1
                COLUMN_NAME
        from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
        where   COLUMN_NAME like '%ProductID'
    ) like '%ProductID'
```

I'm aware how syntactically ridiculous this is however I put it here to give you an idea where my thought process was headed and was also hoping that based on this I could get feedback as to a better method of only running a query when there's a column in the database that matches a condition that you specify? I don't see any purpose for it anywhere - I'm just curious and think I could learn from this.

Comment: `delete` this question and edit the other one.

Comment: I intentionally avoided doing that as it's unclear if that's what the other question was asking and I wanted to give OP an opportunity to edit his own thread to be clearer. Should I do it anyway?

Comment: Are you trying to make your SQL version aware or something? (like when your application moves to a new version and connects to an old DB) Because I think this really isn't the way to do it. I'd do my verifications of columns separately from my actual data access. As you said yourself: there's little to no use to what you are trying right now so I'd propose you pick up a better subject to learn with because this is like going: I'm inventing an interstellar portal device for mowing my lawn! :)

Comment: @IvanL - No, just doing this for educations sake. Couldn't solve the problem so I believe it's worth asking the question - If you see above I explained how I ended up trying this. Dropping it because I couldn't solve it to do something else would be counter-productive and I'd rather see these problems end to end as I believe that's a better learning process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can do it using system view [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE name LIKE '%ProductID')
SELECT *
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Order Details]
```

Comment: Just tried this and it doesn't appear to return any results even though the column name definitely exists. Also broke the first query out on its own and received no results. Unsure why personally but happy to try a few things if you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL, column references must be fixed and known to be valid at the time the query is prepared.  It's not legal for the column name to turn out to be invalid in hindsight, after the query begins executing.

The solution given by @Igor gets around this by running two queries, the first to test the system tables and then conditionally run the second.  You can't do both in one query.